# what is difference between sprite.width VS sprite.scaleX

Tags: actionscript-3

Both of sprite.width and sprite.scaleX can be used for scale a sprite. Is possible sprite.scaleX depends on screen size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change the width property, the scaleX property changes accordingly

```
var rect:Shape = new Shape();
rect.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
rect.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
trace(rect.scaleX) // 1;
rect.width = 200;
trace(rect.scaleX) // 2;
```

[official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#width)

Comment: So, where are only difference. Attribute width is used for concrete numbers of pixels, and scaleX is used for ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the official documentation about [scaleX](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scaleX) and [width](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#width).

By default, `scaleX=1` which means there is no rescaling of the sprite, it does not depend on anything, you may set it freely.